# How to make case statement work only once?

Tags: postgresql, case

I have a table with numeric features like this:

```
animal: id, code, horns, equids
```

I need to make a case statement to determine what kind of animal it is.

```
case when horns =1 and equids = 1 then 'deer'
else case when horns = 1 and equids = 0 then 'rhino'
end end animal
```

But sometimes for one animal code there can be different features like this.

```
id, code, horns, equids, animal
1 , 111 , 1    , 1     , deer
1 , 111 , 1    , 0     , rhino
```

And my case statement first time determines it as deer, and then as rhino.
Is it possible to make that case statement determines for each animal code only once?

Comment: And what would be the result for code `111`: deer or rhino?

Comment: Something one. I need to group by animals and sum them. But because of this problem, I get some more animals then I need.

Comment: It's a case _expression_, not a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pick a random answer, you can compute it as you do then keep distinct records according to `code`.

On a side note, you don't need nested case statements

```sql
WITH src(id, code, horns, equids) AS (values 
    (1 , 111 , 1    , 1),
    (1 , 111 , 1    , 0))
SELECT DISTINCT on (code) *, 
    case when horns = 1 and equids = 1 then 'deer'
         when horns = 1 and equids = 0 then 'rhino'
    end animal
FROM src;

 id | code | horns | equids | animal
----+------+-------+--------+--------
  1 |  111 |     1 |      1 | deer
(1 row)
```